# How do I transform a document before I assign it to a structure in Go using MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, go, internationalization, bson

I am writing a multilingual API with go and mongodb. I have a mongo db document with format:

```
{
  _id : ObjectID(bla)
  "key" : {
    "en" : "Hello",
    "es" : "Hola"
  }
}
```

However, the API needs report json in the form:

```
{
  _id : ObjectID(bla),
  "key" : "Hola"
}
```

if the client sends language headers.

Is there an easy/efficent way to do this? The only working solution I have is to make two separate structs and then merge them together with a bunch of switch/case statements, like:

```
var api MyStruct
var mgo MyMgoStruct
session.DB("db").C("col").Find(nil).One(&mgo)

api.ID = mgo.ID
switch lang {
  default:
    {
      api.Key = string(mgo.Key.En)
    }
  case "es":
    {
      api.Key = string(mgo.Key.Es)
    }
}
```

Structure defs:

```
type Translation struct {
  En string `bson:"en"`
  Es string `bson:"es"`
}

type MyStruct struct {
  ID bson.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
  Key string `json:"key" bson:"key"`
}

type MyMgoStruct struct {
  ID bson.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
  Key Translation `json:"key" bson:"key"`
}
```

I foresee this becoming a huge pain to maintain, as my structures have tens of translated fields. I would prefer a way to transform the MongoDB document, replacing the Translation json structure with a simple key-value pair as in the MyStruct struct.

Comment: You could create two different collections (tables) and if your using mongo 3.2 or higher you can use the look up feature. The first table contains language information that can look up the proper information in the second table... The other approach is to store the information in a single language and translate it before sending the response, instead of storing a translated version. I think the second approach is best. You can use a single struct. And it's much easier to support more then two langauages by writing more translation functions.

Answer (score 1):

> The only working solution I have is to make two separate structs and then merge them together with a bunch of switch/case statements

An alternative is you could use MongoDB projection on the [Find()](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Find). Given your example document format, for example:

```
// Client input language header as variable
var languageInput = "es"  

// Concatenate to get field nest 'key'
key := "key." + languageInput 

// Only project the specific fields
cursor := coll.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{key: 1})
```

See also [Project fields to return from query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

If you have many translation fields in your struct that you don't want to map, you could utilise `bson inline`. For example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId      `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    OtherFields bson.M             `bson:",inline"`
}
```

This would capture unstructured fields in `OtherFields`. See also [bson.Marshal](https://gowalker.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Marshal)